# Swing JList resize bounds

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, desktop-application

I have this JList on my JFrom that keeps expanding both horizontally and vertically as i re-size the JForm.

Netbeans Editor gives you and option to select if some component is Horizontaly / Verticaly re-sizable how can i do that by hand in code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What worked for me is:

```
JScrollList list = new JScrollList(new JList);
list.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(200, 600));
list.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(200, 35700));
```

If you want to know how Netbeans GUI Editor does it open a new JFrame add the component set its size bounds then look up the source of the class.